# How can I add border radius to the first and last elements with a specific class

Tags: html, css, vue.js, calendar

I have a calendar and I'm using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-datepicker) and I want to make sure these borders are filled in.
[image: Calendar Sreenshot]

Tried something here but works only if I select both dates.
I want it to work in the hover state as well.

https://codepen.io/garine519/pen/XWVOePO?editors=1111

*selected elements have `.active` class*

*items hovered within range have `.hover-in-range` class*

*when the end date is selected, `.hover-in-range` class turns into `.in-range`*

Comment: how is that suppose to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
.active:first-child {
 border-radius: 50% 0 0 50%
}

.in-range:last-child {
 border-radius: 0 50% 50% 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get start active with:

```
td.cell:not(.in-range) + .active {
    background: red;
}
```

and end active with:

```
td.cell.in-range + .active {
    background: #2800ff;
}
```

I changed the background for example:
[image]